# Scroll below on new event in React-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, google-calendar-api, react-big-calendar

I am trying to scroll down when I selecting a new slot to create an event but the calendar doesn't scroll below the current browser window height.

In the screenshot below, I am trying to scroll down below 12:30 pm but can't scroll down below the current browser window. Please do let me know why I am not able to scroll down or have a scroll into view working.

Thanks

[image: View Calendar]